# How to stick div and make it not to hide on the bottom of the page while scrolling

Tags: html, css

Here is the sample [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Semkaa/b6Lrc/9/)!
If the result area is too small and you will have to scroll down - some of featuresMenu text will hide behind the footer. How to prevent this, how to make featuresMenu to stick until it reaches footer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  margin-bottom:50px;
}

#div_id {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}
```

this should do the trick, make sure whatever the height of div is you make a margin at the bottom of the page, so stuff doesn't hide there

Answer (score 0):

Set the z-index of the floating div to 1, and the z-index of the footerdiv to -1.

Comment: Here is the [result:](http://img.leprosorium.com/1345240) but I need that 'eee ddd' list not to overlay the footer.